Does this Harita smriti verse imply intercourse as mandatory for marriage to be completed?
"गन्धर्वो विवाहः संज्ञो यः प्रेम्णा स्वेच्छया कृतः।
अन्योन्यस्नेहसंयुक्तौ युवयोर्यः स समाहितः।"
Does this verse imply sexual intercourse as a prerequisite for gandharva vivaha?
